# Is it a convention in Python documentation to include parentheses after function/method names?

Tags: python

My experience in reading Python documentation is that when referring to a function/method one include parentheses after the name. For example,

```
 "... the function f() does ... "
```

rather than

```
 "... the function f does ... "
```

I think that's a good idea, and I generally follow that convention. But I can't find a statement of such a convention anywhere. Is there one, or am I making this up?

Comment: Did you read https://devguide.python.org/documenting/#documenting? Note that the documentation is generated from RST with Sphinx, those parentheses generally appear in the context of *links*, that isn't being written by the author. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs,  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/Doc/library/functions.rst, where `:meth:\`__abs__\`` becomes `__abs__()`.

Comment: @RussAbbott this was a question also I had (Never posted it, just had it awhile ago) thanks for posting this!

Comment: @WilliamMartens Thanks for your support.   @jonsharpe I did look at the devguide documentation. Didn't see anything that answered my question, although didn't read it in detail. Your __abs__() example is exactly what I'm talking about. Hadn't noticed that these are generally links. Scroll down to `class complex`. It contains a sentence beginning "If __complex__() is not defined ..." where `__complex__()` is not a link. The raw version includes the `()`.

Answer (score 3):

`()` in Python means that the specific object is callable... I guess that's why they write `f()` instead of `f` to explicitly state that.

Comment: How do you know that `()` means an object is callable? Is that an explicit convention written down somewhere?

Comment: @RussAbbott - you can use the builtin [`callable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) to check if something is callable. that checks for the presence of `__call__` on the object, which is invoked when using `x(args)`. that's all to say that `()` does indicate something is callable.

Comment: I notice that you didn't write: "that checks for the presence of `__call__()` on the object"

Comment: very nice @RussAbbott :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally It's better to read a text where the function is clearly distinguishable from other variables/texts.

If It's written down somewhere, I am sure you can find it in the [PEP style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).